# What is the source for "asi aseh v'dachi lo sa'aseh"?

Tags: sources-mekorot, talmud-gemara

Throughout Shas we have a concept of "asi aseh v'dachi lo sa'aseh," that a positive commandment overrides a negative commandment (ex. Beitzah 8a, Yevamos 84a, etc.). What is the source for this concept? Where does the Gemara get it from? Is it a sevara, or does it derive it from a passuk?

Comment: Rabbi David Feinstein mentioned a homiletic idea once. Would you be interested in that type of answer?

Comment: @user6591 Ideally I was looking for something in the Gemara itself, or a Peirush on the Gemara, that discussed it.

Comment: shaaynez. gedilim

Comment: @kouty That's an application of it, but is that the source? We also see it by the mussaf on Shabbos, by yibum, and by tzara'as on the makom habris, to name a few.

Comment: יש סמיכות i think if I remember that thi isvthe source, why not learn the first pages of yebamot?

Comment: From He.Wikipedia  -  https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A2%D7%A9%D7%94_%D7%93%D7%95%D7%97%D7%94_%D7%9C%D7%90_%D7%AA%D7%A2%D7%A9%D7%94 - it would seems there's no "source" for this.